# Delegate SystemAction as constructor parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, interface

I have a winform I'm working on that needs change a label when it hits a specific phase and the same label when it's complete. I have an interface setup and a class that implements this interface. In the class constructor, I'm trying to add the Action<> as a parameter but I am having trouble processing what I need to do in order to get it to flow correctly.

Never could get it to work :/

Comment: Let's calrify some things, where do you instance that class? inside the form or outside? and the form, is the main form or a form instanced manually?

Comment: Technically, I have another class, which is a manager, that instantiates all the classes that implement several different interfaces. Then, on the form, I just instantiate the manager class. The form is a main form.

Answer (score 0):

While your example i cannot give specific example because it confuses me. I can still answer some questions.

Does this help?

```
        private Action _methodOnProgress;
        public ChipLoadFirmware(Action method)
        {
            _methodOnProgress = method;
        }
        public bool LoadFirmWare()
        {
            (p) = > 
            {
                _methodOnProgress();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say the example confuses you, can I clarify some things for you for a better solution?

Comment: Changed the example lets hope its better now, Simplyfying the question would help me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an event pattern here will be more reliable.

First add a

```
public event EventHandler Progress
```

to your ChipLoadFirmware class, and make it public in the manager class (lets assume it's called Manager and the ChiLoad instance is called Loader)

So, when you instance the manager in the form you add

```
Manager.Loader.Progress += (o, e) => { /* Change the label */  };
```

And finally in the (p) => { } do

```
Progress(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

**EDIT** Here is your code with the changes, supose the class Form is your form and labelToChange the label which must be changed;

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an object that can load the firmware
/// </summary>
public interface ILoadFirmware
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads firmware on a device
    /// </summary>
    bool LoadFirmware();
    event EventHandler Progress;
    event EventHandler Status;
}

public class ChipLoadFirmware : ILoadFirmware
{
    private readonly log4net.ILog logger = Logging.Log4NetManager.GetLogger();
    private readonly ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader ();
    private bool abort = false;
    private string cmdText = string.Empty;
    private string errortext = string.Empty;
    private string isaIp;
    public event EventHandler Progress;
    public event EventHandler Status;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up an ImageLoader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isaTargetIpAddress">The IP address of the ISA to load the firmware on</param>
    public ChipLoadFirmware (string isaTargetIpAddress)
    {
        this.isaIp = isaTargetIpAddress;
        imageLoader.EventHandler += (s, e) => { };
        logger.DebugFormat("Using IP Address {0}", isaTargetIpAddress);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the firmware onto the device
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns true if successful</returns>
    public bool LoadFirmware()
    {
        bool result = imageLoader.Run(this.isaIp,
            false,
            Command.Command,
            string.Empty,
            CommandFlag.CommandFlag,
            2000,
            (p) => { Progress(this, EventArgs.Empty); },
            (s) => { Status(this, EventArgs.Empty); },
            ref this.abort,
            out this.cmdText,
            out this.errortext);

        if (!result)
        {
            result = false;
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format(
                    "ImageLoader failed with message: {0}",
                    errortext));
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class CalibrationManager : ICalibrationManager
{
    const uint startAddress = 0x00000000;
    const uint startAddress = 0x00000000;

    private readonly log4net.ILog logger;
    private readonly ISignalGenerator sigGenerator;
    public readonly ILoadFirmware loadFirmware;
    private readonly IReader reader;
    private readonly IValueParser valueParser;
    private readonly IRepository<CalibrationValue> calibrationRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<UIDList> uidRepository;

    private string uid;

    public CalibrationManager(ISignalGenerator sigGen, ILoadFirmware loadFirmware, IReader chipRreader, IValueParser chipValueParser, IRepository<UIDList> uidRepo, IRepository<CalibrationValue> calRepo)
    {
        if (sigGen == null ||
            loadFirmware == null ||
            chipReader == null ||
            chipValueParser == null ||
            calRepo == null ||
            uidRepo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        logger = Logging.Log4NetManager.GetLogger();

        this.sigGenerator = sigGen;
        this.loadFirmware = loadFirmware;
        this.reader = chipReader;
        this.valueParser = chipValueParser;
        this.uidRepository = uidRepo;
        this.calibrationRepository = calRepo;
    }

    public void Calibrate(bool reuse)
    {
        int voltageG;
        int currentG;
        // Read uid from device
        this.uid = uidReader.ReadUid();
        logger.DebugFormat("Read UID {0}", this.uid);

        var possibleCalibrations = getCalibrationDataFromRepo();
        if (possibleCalibrations.Any() && reuse)
        {
            logger.Debug("Reusing existing values");
            var existingCalibration = possibleCalibrations.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCalibrated).First();
            currentG = existingCalibration.CurrentGain;
            voltageG = existingCalibration.VoltageGain;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Debug("Reading new values");

            // Set voltage and current for signal generator
            sigGenerator.SetOutput(187, 60);

            // Load firmware onto chip for CLI commands
            loadFirmware.LoadFirmware();
            UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice.LoadFirmware);

            // Read voltage from device and calibrate
            voltageG = valueParser.ReadVoltageValue();
            UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice.CalibrateVoltage);

            // Read current from device and calibrate
            sigGenerator.SetOutput(38, 60);
            currentG = valueParser.ReadCurrentValue();
            UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice.CalibrateCurrent);

            // Insert values into table
            CalibrationValue cv = new CalibrationValue();
            cv.UidId = uidRepository.GetBy(e => e.UID.Equals(this.uid)).Id;
            cv.CurrentGain = currentG;
            cv.VoltageGain = voltageG;
            calibrationRepository.Insert(cv);
            calibrationRepository.Submit();
            UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice.DatabaseInsert);
        }

        logger.DebugFormat("Updated database for current gain to {0} and voltage gain to {1}", currentG, voltageG);

        // Once here, device has passed all phases and device is calibrated
        UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice.CalibrationComplete);
    }

    private IQueryable<CalibrationValue> getCalibrationDataFromRepo()
    {
        int uidId = uidRepository.GetBy(e => e.UID.Equals(this.uid)).Id;
        return calibrationRepository.SearchFor(c => c.UidId == uidId);
    }

    public bool CalibrationDataExists()
    {
        this.uid = uidReader.ReadUid();
        logger.DebugFormat("Read UID {0}", this.uid);

        return getCalibrationDataFromRepo().Any();
    }

    public event Action<StateOfDevice, string> StateChange;

    private void UpdateStateChange(StateOfDevice state, string message = "")
    {
        var sc = StateChange;
        if (sc != null)
        {
            StateChange(state, message);
        }
    }
}

public class Form
{
    Label labelToModify;

    void MagickButtonClick(object Source, EventArgs e)
    { 

        CalibrationManager manager = new CalibrationManager(.......);

        manager.loadFirmware.Progress += (o, e) => { labelToModify.Text = "Some progress achieved!!";  };

    }

}
```

Comment: I added the manager class to the example using your answer but cannot seem to fire the event from the form. Can you look at it please? Thanks for the hlpe

Comment: Yes, first, make loadFirmware public in CalibrationManager and not of type ILoadFirmware but ChipCalibrationFirmware (if you need to be ILoadFirmware then the events must be in the interface and implemented by ChipLoadFirmware), then in the form where you create the manager do manager.loadFirmware.Progress += (o, e) => { /* Change the label */  };

Comment: Guess I'm confused on where to go from here. Yes, I need it to be of type ILoadFirmware so I added the `public event EventHandler Progress;
        public event EventHandler Status;` to ILoadFirmware. Can you show me what you mean in your example please? Thanks again.

Comment: This is where it isn't working for me:
`manager.loadFirmware.Progress += (o, e) => { labelToModify.Text = "Some progress achieved!!";  };`. When I call manager. loadFirmware isn't there :/. I have it public in the ChipLoadFirmware class.

Comment: EDIT: Do I need it in the CalibrationManager as public instead of ChipLoadFirmware?

Comment: Any more ideas on the Gusman? Still banging my head on this :/